# MERGE INTO ONE ROW

Tags: oracle12c

i have table like this

```
    HONS        S.S.C      H.S.C        APPLICANT_ID

    null         null       H.S.C-1       1
    null         S.S.C-1     null         1
 B.S.C HONS - 1  null        null         1
```

I want the output like this

```
 HONS             S.S.C      H.S.C        APPLICANT_ID

B.S.C HONS - 1   S.S.C-1     H.S.C-1        1
```

what will be the query of it?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Hope this helps !

```
SELECT MAX(HONS) HONS, MAX(SSC) SSC, MAX(HSC) HSC, MAX(APPLICANT_ID) APPLICANT_ID FROM
(
select null HONS, null SSC, 'HSC-1' HSC, 1 APPLICANT_ID from dual
union
select null HONS, 'SSC-1' SSC, null HSC, 1 APPLICANT_ID from dual
union
select 'BSC-HONS' HONS, null SSC, 'HSC-1' HSC, 1 APPLICANT_ID from dual
);
```